# Python facebook desktop application

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, desktop-application

I'm trying to make a desktop application in python 2.7 (I'm using python-facebook-sdk) which would allow user to log into his account and then do some basic actions (like displaying his wall messages, for starters). I have set up my app, have my ID/SECRET handy, but really don't know how to handle the first step of authentication.

I can invoke the log in dialog in a browser window by using the webbrowser library (although it would be better if that window popped up in my app gui, so any advice on implementing this would be appreciated), however I have no idea how to intercept this redirected URL with my application in order to extract the information I need for obtaining the access url with.

I'm pretty sure that I won't be able to use the webbrowser lib in the end, but what libraries/methods should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up a mini webserver in Python that Facebook can redirect to. I'd check this out: http://blog.carduner.net/2010/05/26/authenticating-with-facebook-on-the-command-line-using-python/